# Authentication Error with mongolite

Tags: r, mongodb

To save data to mongodb (using the `mongolite` package from CRAN), I defined the following function:

```
  saveData <- function(data, collection) {
    # Connect to the database
    db <- mongo(collection = collection,
                url = paste0(
                  "mongodb://",
                  options()$mongodb$username, ":",
                  options()$mongodb$password, "@",
                  options()$mongodb$host, "/",
                  databaseName))
    # Insert the data into the mongo collection as a data.frame
    data <- as.data.frame(t(data))
    db$insert(data)
  }
```

My data is stored in a matrix that looks something like this:

```
> mat.answers
  var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
1    90       60          70      60      50
2    85       65          75      55      50
3    80       70          75      70      25
4    75       70          80      80      55
5    80       66          80      75      55
```

However, when I'm using the command to save some data, I get the following error:

```
saveData(df.answers,"SST")
Mongo Message: SCRAM: authenticating "dynamo" (step 1)
Error: Authentication failed.
Called from: mongo_collection_command_simple(col, "{\"ping\":1}")
Browse[1]>
```

I generated a user and enabled authentication in the mongodb configuration file. From the `mongo` shell, I can log in just fine with these credentials. It does neither work for local databases, nor does it connect to a remote one provided by mongolab.

Comment: does `paste0(
                  "mongodb://",
                  options()$mongodb$username, ":",
                  options()$mongodb$password, "@",
                  options()$mongodb$host, "/",
                  databaseName)` give you a valid URL?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having an issue b/c my auth database `admin` isn't the database where my data is. But according to the documentation I have to put the auth database at the end of the uri

Answer (score 3):

I found that the following command allowed me to connect to mongodb using mongolite and the legacy SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication mode.

```
library(mongolite)
mongoUrl <- "mongodb://a_username:a_password@localhost:27017/admin" #<-admin here is the mongodb database that stores the authentication info

# specify your collection
colname <- "a_collection"

# specify your database
dbname <- "a_database"

# create connection (con)
con <- mongo(collection = colname, url = mongoUrl, db=dbname)

# count how many records (fyi this is just a test)
con$count('{}')
```